# How to pass environment variables to Docker compose with a make file

Tags: docker, makefile, devops

We have a line in our Makefile which reads the env file and exports the variables to the shell:

```sh
include .env
export $(shell sed 's/=.*//' .env)
```

This enables the usage of the variables in a make file task like

```sh
connect-db:
    docker-compose exec mysql mysql --host=0.0.0.0 --user=${DATABASE_USER} --password=${DATABASE_PASSWORD} ${DATABASE_NAME}
```

But there also services in the docker-compose file, which are using environment variables as volume names.

```yaml
  yarn:
    image: node:10
    entrypoint: "yarn"
    command: "help"
    volumes:
      - ${YARN_HOME}:/yarn
      - ${PROJECT_DIR}:/opt/project
      - ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}:/ssh_agent
      - ${SSH_ID_RSA}:/node/.ssh/id_rsa:ro
    environment:
      SSH_AUTH_SOCK: ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
      GIT_SSH_COMMAND: "ssh -i /node/.ssh/id_rsa -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no"
      YARN_CACHE_FOLDER: "/yarn"
      PROJECT_DIR: ${PROJECT_DIR}
      YARN_HOME: ${YARN_HOME}
    working_dir: /opt/project
```

When I run `docker-compose run yarn` the container is correctly executed, but if I run a make task with this docker-compose command, an error is logged

```
make yarn
docker-compose run --rm yarn
ERROR: Cannot create container for service yarn: create .: volume name is too short, names should be at least two alphanumeric characters
```

When disable the lines with the include .env the task works but the task which uses the variables not.

How can I use environment variables in both situations?

Comment: Compose isn't really built for the setup you describe; writing out the `docker run` command in the Makefile might work a little better.  But, why not just run `yarn` directly on the host?  It will have direct access to the ssh agent, user home directories, relative paths, _etc._ without jumping through all of these hoops.

Comment: To me it seems like `make` exports some variable that resolves to `.`, would that be `PROJECT_DIR`? Don't you have it defined somewhere in the `Makefile`?